# RMagick fails to install using bundler, installs correctly using RubyGems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, bundler, rmagick

On my Ubuntu 10.04 machine I'm having some issues installing RMagick (Ruby's ImageMagick gem), both with the regular imagemagick packages from apt and with ImageMagick compiled from source. 
The issue so far is that `bundle install` fails to install rmagick, whereas RubyGems works just fine. My output is the following:

```
root@li264-104:/home/user/www/test/public# bundle install
[..cut..]
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb 

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/www/test/public/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/www/test/public/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle:13
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19
root@li264-104:/home/user/www/test/public# cat /home/user/www/test/public/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

Also, running the last contents of gem_make.out manually runs successfully:

```
======================================================================
Thu 19Jan12 16:42:10
This installation of RMagick 2.13.1 is configured for
Ruby 1.8.7 (i686-linux) and ImageMagick 6.7.4 Q8
======================================================================
```

And also installing using RubyGems works just fine on this machine, making it hard to localize the actual error:

```
root@li264-104:/home/user/www/test/public# gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...
```

I'm definitely hoping anyone has some pointers. The behavior found looks a lot like the issue in [curb gem installation: bundle install fails, but normal gem install works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915530/curb-gem-installation-bundle-install-fails-but-normal-gem-install-works), sadly this issue has no solution posted (and I'm not short on memory). Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `sudo bundle install`?

Comment: is there just one ruby/rubygems installed? what does `which gem` and `which bundle`say?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @PinnyM `sudo bundle install` gives me the same output as running `bundle install` as root sadly. @phoet, there should just be one installed, this machine has no RVM or whatsoever installed. The paths are `/usr/local/bin/gem` and `/usr/local/bin/bundle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been unable to find any solution for the issue and instead installed rvm, which did work correctly.